# 777'd some files. How do I repair SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, permissions

So I'm messing around on a test server and accidentally ran the following (which resulting in SSH breaking):

```
# chmod -R 777 /var
```

Because it's a test server, I'd rather not re-install right now, I have things I would like to test.

I understand that `777` is very bad set of mode bits on a live server, and so I already understand that it would be a very bad thing to do on a server with anything valuable on it.

Is there anyway to get SSH functioning again?

Comment: please share exactly what you did, what files you chmod'ed and what errors does ssh give you. we can't help you otherwise.

Comment: `sshd` expects certain files to be set 600, I think, but as schaiba says, it should hint clearly at the problem.

Comment: I did a chmod 777 -R on /var

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reset all UIDs and GIDs:

```
for i in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $i; done
```

Reset all permissions:

```
for i in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $i; done
```

Try to restart:

```
service sshd restart
```

Does that help?

Comment: Restart may not work, if it is not started already.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you probably broke things by removing setuid and setgid bits on executables that needed them.  You may be able to repair things by figuring out which particular files ought to be setuid or setgid and fixing them - by comparing against another machine that's still working, for instance.

Comment: I did a chmod 777 -R on /var